# How to use JSDoc to document a factory function that returns an object with public methods?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I have the following factory function:

```
/**
 * Create a CRUD interface
 * @param {string} collectionName Name of the table/collection on the API side
 * @return {Object}
 */
export default function createCrudInterface(collectionName) {
  return {
    /**
     * Create a new item
     * @param {Object} data JSON request data
     * @param {import('./api-call').ApiOptions} [apiOptions] API call options
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    create(data, apiOptions) {
      return apiCall('POST', `/${collectionName}`, null, data, apiOptions);
    },

    /**
     * Gets one or more items
     * @param {(string|number)} [id] ID of item
     * @param {Object} [queryParams] Query parameters
     * @param {import('./api-call').ApiOptions} [apiOptions] API call options
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    get(id, queryParams, apiOptions) {
      return apiCall(
        'GET',
        `/${collectionName}` + (id && `/${id}`),
        queryParams,
        null,
        apiOptions
      );
    },

    /**
     * Update an item
     * @param {(string|number)} id ID of item
     * @param {Object} data JSON request data
     * @param {import('./api-call').ApiOptions} [apiOptions] API call options
     * @return {Promise}
     */
    update(id, data, apiOptions) {
      return apiCall('PUT', `/${collectionName}/${id}`, null, data, apiOptions);
    },

    /**
     * Delete one or more items
     * @param {(string|number|string[]|number[])} idOrIds ID of item
     * @param {import('./api-call').ApiOptions} [apiOptions] API call options
     */
    delete(idOrIds, apiOptions) {
      const batch = Array.isArray(idOrIds);

      return apiCall(
        'DELETE',
        `/${collectionName}` + (batch ? '' : `/${idOrIds}`),
        null,
        batch ? { ids: idOrIds } : null,
        apiOptions
      );
    },
  };
}
```

This *seems* like it would work, but it doesn't:

```
const blah = createCrudInterface('blah');
```

When I type `blah.create(`, the VS Code IntelliSense has no idea what to suggest. It's not pulling the method JSDoc that I've defined.

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: It's an open issue at the moment. https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1244

Comment: I gave up and went with using TypeScript.